# Как получить доступ к файлам Linux/Ubuntu из Windows 10 WSL?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, docker, wsl2

Этот вопрос проистекает из вопроса, как получить доступ к файлам Windows из Ubuntu Bash, но как я могу сделать обратное?

В частности, мне нужно получить доступ к моему SSH-ключу из Windows, который находится в /home/mark/.ssh/id_rsa под Bash.

И еще, как возможно открыть, например, в популярном редакторе phpStorm в винде проект расположенный на виртуальной машине (контейнере) Ubuntu?

В качестве предисловия, я установил WSL в командной строке cmd, после чего выполнил команду:

```
wsl --install -d Ubuntu
```

Затем проверил командой `wsl -l -v` в запуске убунты.

После чего установил Docker Desktop for Windows и связал его с убунтой (виртуальной машиной) в настройках. Когда я перехожу в консоль убунты, пытаюсь ввести команду `explorer.exe` открывается окно с файлами и папками, но только увы содержимое это явно не файловая структура убунты.

Comment: Извините, а вообще на кой чёрт вы спрятали ваш ssh ключ внутри wsl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант 1: набрать в консоли wsl

```
explorer.exe .
```

Точка через пробел. Открывает содержимое текущего каталога :)

Вариант 2: в открытом эксполере ввести путь `\\wsl$`

Comment: команда explorer.exe . открывает папку C:\Windows\System32 откуда начинается вызов командной строки от администратора. А второй вариант работает. И что же, как можно в phpStorm открыть каталог с проектом на убунте?

Comment: @IntegralAL чисто для искусства - да. Но там есть масса всяческих нюансов и странностей. Я пробовал в прошлом году Idea и отказался от этой затеи, так как была путаница с терминалами и в какой же системе запускать сборки :) Возможно, в вашем случае будет проще https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010723500-Is-it-possible-to-open-PHPStorm-from-WSL-using-pstorm-command-

Я бы рекомендовал запускаться через Gateway https://www.jetbrains.com/ru-ru/remote-development/gateway/

Comment: Не смог добраться до второй ссылки, про gateway, она битая. Спасибо за ответы. Поставлю ответ ваш, как правильный.